# Expression _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) Error

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, reference, stack

After adding parameter by reference "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" debug assertion failed.

```
class Stack
{
private:
    const std::uint32_t m_maxElement;

protected:
    std::uint32_t m_currentElement;
    int *m_tab;

public:
    Stack(std::uint32_t p_maxElement);
    virtual ~Stack();
    void push(int p_element);
    std::int32_t pop(void);
    std::uint32_t size(void) const;
};

Stack::Stack(std::uint32_t p_maxElement) : m_maxElement(p_maxElement), m_tab(new int[m_maxElement]), m_currentElement(0u)
{}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    if (m_tab) delete[] m_tab;
}

void Stack::push(int p_element)
{
    if (m_currentElement < m_maxElement)
    {
        m_tab[m_currentElement] = p_element;
        ++m_currentElement;
    }
}

std::int32_t Stack::pop()
{
    if (m_currentElement > 0u)
    {
        return m_tab[--m_currentElement];
    }
}

std::uint32_t Stack::size() const
{
    return m_currentElement;
}
/*************************************************************************/

std::int32_t median(Stack p_stack)
{
    std::vector<std::int32_t> l_container(p_stack.size());
    while (p_stack.size())
    {
        l_container.push_back(p_stack.pop());
    }
    std::sort(l_container.begin(), l_container.end());
    int l_containerSize = l_container.size();
    int l_middleIndex = l_containerSize / 2;
    if (l_containerSize % 2 == 0)
    {
        int l_firstMiddleElement = l_container[l_middleIndex - 1];
        int l_secondMiddleElement = l_container[l_middleIndex];
        return (l_firstMiddleElement + l_secondMiddleElement) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return l_container[l_middleIndex];
    }
    return 0;
}

std::int32_t arithmeticAverage(Stack p_stack)
{
    std::int32_t l_sum = 0;
    int l_stackSize = p_stack.size();
    while (p_stack.size())
    {
        l_sum = p_stack.pop();
    }
    return l_sum / l_stackSize;
}

int main()
{
    Stack firstStack(10);
    firstStack.push(2);
    firstStack.push(4);
    firstStack.push(8);
    std::cout << "firstStack.pop() = " << firstStack.pop() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "median(firstStack) = " << median(firstStack) << std::endl
    std::cout << "arithmeticAverage(firstStack) = " << arithmeticAverage(firstStack) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In case of

```
std::int32_t median(Stack &p_stack)
```

is ok. Instead of
    std::int32_t median(Stack p_stack)
After that line "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" appears.

Comment: If the copy of the Stack object is destroyed you are freeing the memory which you in the later call want to use again, therefore you get this error as you are accessing unallocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `median` function takes `Stack` by value the compiler has to make a copy of the original `Stack`. Because you have not defined a copy constructor in `Stack` the compiler generated its own which does member wise copy which means it just copies the value of the pointer over so that two instances of `Stack` now point at the same bit of memory. Then when the `median` function finishes execution the destructor of the copy is called and deletes the memory therefore now the original `Stack` in your main is pointing at a block that has been freed which causes the error.

When `median` takes a reference there is no copy being made - it gets a reference to the original `Stack` in `main` and no destructor gets called.

I suggest you change your code so that `median` and the other function take a `const` reference to `Stack` as their parameters.

Comment: Your explanation is good enough but you can`t use const reference because of fact that median function is calling pop() method.

Comment: Well yes I missed that. However if the median function uses pop and basically empties the stack then the arithmeticAverage will get an empty stack so its output is not going to be what you expect. So you either need to copy the stack or use something else that can be inspected by the functions without changing the data.